# Replacing values in column of list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list of lists with column names and am trying to replace the values of a column. My lists containing all lists called `all_lists` looks as such:

```
[[1]]
       preds     ground_truth
19221  0.0566264            1
6587   0.0567813            0
3981   0.0569643            0
16956  0.0570841            1
2344   0.0570878            1
2855   0.0571354            1

[[2]]
       preds     ground_truth
17326  0.7525393            0
26342  0.7586699            1
15996  0.7703387            1
14033  0.7738193            0
3403   0.7838794            1
20626  0.8009424            1
16675  0.8294433            1

[[3]]
[1] preds   ground_truth
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I am trying to get all values in `preds` columns of 0.5 and above to be 1 and all values less than 0.5 to be 0. My solution attempt was this:

```
for (lists in all_lists){
  lists[preds] <- ifelse(lists[preds] > 0.5, 1, 0)
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `round` the `preds` column in `all_lists` :

```
all_lists <- lapply(all_lists, function(x) {
  x$preds = round(x$preds)
  #If your data can go above 1
  #x$preds = as.integer(x$preds > 0.5)
  x
})
```

Comment: That's great thanks. Just as a bonus question, do you know how to get the auc of each of these groups? I have tried `auc(lists[ground_truth], lists[preds.hold])`  But it says `ground_truth` not found

Comment: I don't have your data but maybe `lapply(all_lists, function(x) auc(x$ground_truth, x$preds.hold))` ?

Answer (score 0):

For a custom threshold, you can use Map:

```
nlist <- Map(function(x) {x$preds <- ifelse(x$preds > 0.5, 1, 0); x}, nlist)
```

---

**Sample Data**

```
df <- data.frame(preds = runif(10), ground=sample(0:1, size = 10, replace = T))
nlist = list(df, df)
```